# Is there some http GET response that I can add to fix an encoding problem on the client web browser?

Tags: http, tcp, embeddedwebserver, http-get, embedded

I have an embedded web server written in C using uIP libraries, in a microcontroller, which outputs the following static text in response to an http get. It is shown below as a C literal string:

```
"HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
"Server: UIP/1.0 (http://www.something.com/)\r\n"
"Content-type: text\html\r\n"
```

Right after that comes the doctype string \ and the \ ... \</html> body of the page requested. I did not write this code, but it was handed to me. Now I try it on Opera, Firefox, and Internet Explorer. The entire webpage is using Ansi/C and no special strings or bytes.  But it loads and displays properly only on Opera.  For some reason this particular uIP based web-browser will not render on IE 8 or Firefox.

![alt text][1]

What can I add to the http headers to make my micro-web-server encoding of basic/default C/ansi codepage  be detected properly for all browsers, and not just opera?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to replace your static text to this one:

```
"HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
"Server: UIP/1.0 (http://www.something.com/)\r\n"
"Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"
```

**NOTE** : the backslash ('\') character is an esacpe character, in your static string, you did "\h" with your "text\html"

**NOTE** : The "charset=utf-8" part is only useful if your files are utf-8 encode

Comment: This is it. except it turns out I need charset=iso-8859-1 (latin1).

Comment: I think it's just BRILLIANT that this worked fine with Opera but nobody else, but that suddenly the latest browsers change their default encode-detection algorithms.

Comment: yes, ISO-8859-1 if your files are latin1 encoded (mostly in Windows). Though ISO-8859-1 doesn't support foreign characters without using html entities and char codes; this is why using utf-8 is far better. Glad it worked :)